# How can we maintain access to the creator a Case at all times, even when its owner has been changed to Queue

Tags: apex, case, servicecloud, apex-managed-sharing, sharing-rule

I had written a Workflow rule based on which a case gets auto-assigned to a "Customer Service Representative" queue. Now the problem is that as soon as the case is created, the creator gets insufficient privileges error. The person won't even know the Case# he generated, let alone the option to add the attachments.
Now I know that it's happening because the owner field gets updated to Queue and the creator loses access to this record, but how record creator maintain access to this record.

We have implemented private sharing model.
Also I don't see the above can be achieved through any sharing based rules.
Do we have to resort to apex based sharing here or am I missing something on the configuration side of cases here ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should leverage [Case Team](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=caseteam_def.htm&type=0)  functionality.**

Basically, whenever Case ownership changes you should add the user to a case team as member and provide read/write access to that user.

Here is the logic:

> - Define case team role.
> - If previous case owner ownerId and new OwnerId are not same then add the user in the team. Also, put a check that, previous owner is a user and not a queue.
> - Also verify that user is not previously exist as case team member of that case.

Refer this below code and use this in `after update` trigger.

```
public void addCaseTeamMembersToCase(List<Case> lstNewCases, Map<Id,Case> mapOldCases)
{
    for(Case objCase:lstNewCases)
    {           
        String oldOwnerId = mapOldCases.get(objCase.Id).ownerId;
        String newOwnerid = objCase.ownerId;

        if(!newOwnerid.equalsIgnoreCase(mapOldCases.get(objCase.Id).ownerId) 
            && oldOwnerId.subString(0,3) == '005')
        {
            //verify if the oldOwnerId ever exists as Case Team members
            List<CaseTeamMember> lstCaseTeamMember = [SELECT MemberId FROM CaseTeamMember
                                                    WHERE ParentId =: objCase.Id
                                                    AND MemberId =: oldOwnerId];

            if(lstCaseTeamMember.size() == 0)
            {
                mapMembersToAdd.put(objCase.Id, 
                   new CaseTeamMember(             
                          ParentId = objCase.Id,                           
                          MemberId = oldOwnerId
                        )
                    ); 
            }            
        }
    }
    if (!mapMembersToAdd.isEmpty())
    {   
        objCaseTeamRole = [SELECT Id
                                  FROM CaseTeamRole 
                                  WHERE Name = '<my team role>' LIMIT 1];
        for (CaseTeamMember objCaseTeamMember : mapMembersToAdd.values())
        {
            objCaseTeamMember.TeamRoleId = objCaseTeamRole.Id;
        }              
        if (!mapMembersToAdd.isEmpty())
        {
            insert mapMembersToAdd.values();
        }

    }   
}
```